# Prerender + Angular JS + Rails works only on second query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, node.js, prerender

I have Angular JS based Rails application splitted to two apps. Frontend which renders HTML and backend plain API app which renders JSON.

I used prerender_rails gem for frontend app and prerender open-source service run locally. I belive I configured middleware properly because queries are handled by frontend and phantom js is working and page is rendering.

The problem is that first ( or sometimes second ) query returns empty page and second query ( sometimes third ) renders proper HTML page. After that every next query on same URL renders proper page.

I run frontend and backend app on Puma with 8 workers each.

Any ideas how to fix it?